# C++ Memory Address Incrementation

Tags: c++, sockets, memory, byte, send

Is there a way for me to take a memory address and advance it a certain amount that is stored in a variable?  And what would that variable type have to be?

For example, in the following code I'd like to first look at data + 0, and then for each step after that look at data + sent. If I'm looking at this correctly, sent is stored as bytes, and data is a memory address.

```
bool sendAll(int socket, const void *data, ssize_t size) {
    ssize_t sent = 0;
    ssize_t just_sent;
    while (sent < size) {
        just_sent = send(socket, data + sent, size - sent, 0);
        if (just_sent < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        sent += just_sent;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `char*` will do.  Pointer math, when the pointer has type `T*`, always works on increments of `sizeof (T)`.  And `sizeof (char) == 1` by definition.

So try:

```
just_sent = send(socket, sent + (const char*)data, size - sent, 0);
```

Comment: My code above doesn't work.  What would I do to change it to work?  Also, the data array that is being used here is an int array that is sent as (void *)data.

Comment: @Rick_Sch: Just replace the one line calling `send` with the version in my answer.

Comment: You are a god. Seriously.  You just helped me figure out something that was taking days to accomplish.

Comment: Note that you are casting `const void*` to `char*` and throwing away the const-qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing @Ben's answer because I think that "Just replace the one line calling send with the version in my answer." isn't a really good answer...

@Rick, what it is important is that you know how many bytes were transferred. No matter if the array is an array of integers, if you want to start from the `sent`-th **byte** you can cast `data` to `(char*)` so the compiler do the correct pointer arithmetic on `(char*)data + sent` adding `sent` bytes to `data`. Thats because `sizeof(char) == 1` byte. If instead, you cast `data` to `(int*)`, instead of shifting `sent` bytes, you would shift `sent * sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: That was a comment, not an answer.  My answer does (and did) explain that pointer arithmetic on `char*` works in units of `sizeof (char) == 1`.